# Mocking a side_effect with Python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to mock out my requests.get to have a status code of `200` and make `history[0].status_code` trigger an `IndexError` (since there were no redirects). I'm able to get `status_code` to return `200`, but when I mock out history with the desired side effect, the `IndexError` is not triggered.

```
@patch('requests.get')
def test_no_redirect(self, mock_requests):
    mock_requests.return_value.status_code = 200
    mock_requests.history[0].status_code.side_effect = IndexError()

    response = requests.get('example.com')

    self.assertRaises(IndexError, response.history[0].status_code)            
    self.assertTrue(200, response.status_code)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you should assign ``IndexError()`` to ``side_effect`` of ``status_code``? Mayby the call to ``history[0]`` should throw the error?

Comment: @Kamil thanks for your suggestion, but I have tried this and it did not raise the exception either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I checked the code and I'd like to mention a few things.

First of all `assertRises` method receives callable as the second parameter ;) 
Its definition looks like this

```
def assertRaises(self, excClass, callableObj=None, *args, **kwargs):
```

The second thing, if you are mocking `status_code` using

```
mock_requests.return_value.status_code = 200
```

why not to try the same with history:

```
mock_requests.return_value.history = []
```

We are using the real list instead of some kind of mock, so I think that it's even better.
The test method could look like this:

```
@patch('requests.get')
def test_no_redirect(self, mock_requests):
    mock_requests.return_value.status_code = 200
    mock_requests.return_value.history = []

    mock_requests.history[0].status_code.side_effect = IndexError

    response = requests.get('example.com')

    self.assertRaises(IndexError, lambda: response.history[0])
    self.assertTrue(200, response.status_code)
```

Comment: So besides the asserRaises not calling a callable, my only mistake was to not set history prior to setting the IndexError then right?

Comment: It seems so :) What's more you could achieve the same result by calling ``mock_requests.return_value.history.__getitem__.side_effect = IndexError`` instead of ``mock_requests.return_value.history = []`` but using simple list is much more readable from my point of view. Simple code is almost always better.